# How can i add exception to php if statement

Tags: php

I have this if statement but how can I add more conditions to it?:

```
if($row['Type']==$rtype){
}
```

I would like to have two conditions so when `$row['Type']=A` and `$rtype=B` and vise versa all others should be match exact but in case when Type A and B comes together I want to allow the statement display result.

I tried by adding:

```
($row['Type']=='A' && $rtype=='B') || ($row['Type']=='B' && $rtype=='A')
```

as:

```
if(...&& (($row['Type']==$rtype) || ($row['Type']=='A' && $rtype=='B') || ($row['Type']=='A' && $rtype=='B'))) {
 }
```

What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: Your problem comes from the fact that you don't define clearly what you want to allow or reject in that condition.  The PHP engine can not guess it and neither can I.  Please make an effort in saying 'I want this to happen when this and that, but not when only this or only that.' or anything relevant.

Comment: @JuliePelletier Thanks, Sorry if my question is not clear enough. i was looking if there is any way to add `ALL EXCEPT` Condition in PHP. basically i want `$row['Type']==$rtype` to be executed but not when value in `$row['Type']`  equals  A and value in `$rtype` equals  B.

Comment: please explain the question

Comment: It's still unclear, especially after rereading the initial question.  Does `if ($row['Type'] == $rtype && $rtype != 'B' && $rtype != 'A')` do what you want?

Comment: You must have to look for [Operator Precedence](http://php.net/manual/pl/language.operators.precedence.php).

Comment: Can you explain the `if` condition you want to check for in plain language or pseudo code? It's not really clear what your question is. Is it operator precedence or something else?

Comment: @tptcat I want to show search result when the two types are the same only `$row['Type']==$rtype` or a==a or b==b or c==c.. but one exception if $row['Type']=a &&  $rtype=b i want to show result show  or the reverse case not when $rtype = c && $row['Type']=d. In all other cases the two variable has to be the same except  a and b

Comment: Ok. You've changed your comment quite a bit so I'm not sure my answer applies any longer. It seems like maybe you have to revisit your logic. Your revised comment sounds pretty convoluted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment above, it sounds like you may need more clearly define when to "show" and when to "not show". Typically, if there are only two scenarios — either show or don't show — then you wouldn't need two `if` conditions.

However, with what you describe above, this should work:

```
if (($rtype == 'A' && $row['Type'] == 'B') || ($rtype == 'B' && $row['Type'] == 'A')) {
    return true;
}

if (($rtype == 'D' && $row['Type'] == 'D') || ($rtype == 'E' && $row['Type'] == 'E') || ($rtype == 'F' && $row['Type'] == 'F') {
    return false;
}
```

Note that each group is contained within its own `(` and `)`. That does the `AND` you're looking for. Outside of each group, the `||` will do the `OR`.

If you know that you don't want to "show" if the first `if` doesn't evaluate to `true`, then you can simply do:

```
if (($rtype == 'A' && $row['Type'] == 'B') || ($rtype == 'B' && $row['Type'] == 'A')) {
    return true;
}

return false;
```

I'm not sure what "show" and "don't show" mean so I'm just assuming a `true/false` will do for you.

Also check out the [Operator Precedence](http://php.net/manual/pl/language.operators.precedence.php) link that abhishek posted above. That might give you some more general knowledge about how to group your logical expressions.